# What is the c# equivalent of Java DecimalFormat?

Tags: c#, java, decimalformat

How would I convert the following code to C#

```
DecimalFormat form 
String pattern = "";
for (int i = 0; i < nPlaces - nDec - 2; i++) {
        pattern += "#";
}
pattern += "0.";
for (int i = nPlaces - nDec; i < nPlaces; i++) {
        pattern += "0";
}
form = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = form.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
form.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
form.setMaximumIntegerDigits(nPlaces - nDec - 1);
form.applyPattern(pattern);
```

**EDIT** The particular problem is that I do not wish the decimal separator to change with Locale (e.g. some Locales would use ',').

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you mention the higher level aim.

Comment: Is there no simple  equivalent? The actual aim is to make sure that FP numbers in different locales while retaing '.' as the decimal separator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For decimal separator you can set it in a `NumberFormatInfo` instance and use it with ToString:

```
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    //** test **
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    decimal d = 125501.0235648m;
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = "?";
    s = d.ToString(nfi); //--> 125501?0235648
```

to have the result of your java version, use the `ToString()` function version with [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) (i.e.: what you called pattern):

```
s = d.ToString("# ### ##0.0000", nfi);// 1245124587.23     --> 1245 124 587?2300
                                      //      24587.235215 -->       24 587?2352
```

[System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In C#, [decimal numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx) are stored in the `decimal` type, with an internal representation that allows you to perform decimal math without rounding errors.

Once you have the number, you can [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(VS.95).aspx) it using [Decimal.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2.aspx) for output purposes.  This formatting is locale-specific; it respects your [current culture setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx).

Comment: To *control* the format, use [Decimal.ToString(IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx)