# Float to string format difference in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#

Currently am porting C# code to JAVA, I am facing few difference in result while formatting float to string. I have included the example code used  in C# and JAVA. I am expecting the same result for JAVA as in C#. Please let me know if there is any possibilities to achieve the same.

**C#:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WF_33868 testClass = new WF_33868();
    testClass.FormatFloat(32233.0089f);
}

private void FormatFloat(float d)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("######################.00######"));
}
```

Answer:32233.01

JAVA:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    WF_33868 testClass = new WF_33868();
    testClass.FormatFloat(32233.0089f);
}

private void FormatFloat(float d) throws Exception 
{
    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("######################.00######").format(d));
}
```

Answer:32233.00976562

Can anyone help me to achieve the exact result as in C#?

Comment: If you want rounding to two decimal places, remove all the trailing '#' characters.  They specify digits that should be displayed if they exist in the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the c# equivalent of Java DecimalFormat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576782/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-java-decimalformat)

Comment: I need the equivalent result as in c#, using decimal format I couldn’t achieve it. I would like to know is there any other approach to achieve the same?